# drap and drop to change order

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, drag-and-drop

i have some rows and want to give user the feature of drag and drop to change their orders. 
how can i implement it? i guess it is possible with jquery. i am also using php.

Answer (score 2):

Check out [jquery UI](http://jqueryui.com/home)'s [**`Draggable`**](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/), [**`Droppable`**](http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/) and [**`Sortable`**](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/) .

Sortable is what you're looking for, but draggable and droppable are good to know about as well because it has a lot to do with the sortable functionality.

Loop through whatever list you have to serialize your data and pass it with w/ [**Ajax**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) if you would like to save any information.

Answer (score 1):

Just had to solve this exact same problem, so might as well add something here in case it helps someone else.

[jQuery UI Sortable](http://jqueryui.com/sortable/) provides the basic client side functionality to reorder items in a nice way, but you still need to persist the order changes.

My solution was write a JQuery plugin that does the following:

- It assumes a table for this example, but with a few changes it will work for a list.
- Locate the `tbody` element of the table (Sortable requires the tbody, not the table, as it reorders the immediate children).
- If the table has a header, insert a blank header column (see why next).
- Insert a drag icon placeholder* as a new `td` (this requires a new column heading)
- Apply sortable to the target element. Supply an update function to catch the drag change and post an Ajax "PUT" to the server specifying the id of the row object, the id of the parent object and the new sort position for the item that was dragged.
- The plugin assumes that the parent container (e.g. the table) has an attribute like `data-id="parentid"` where parentid is the unique id of the parent item to which the rows belong
- The plugin assumes that each displayed row (e.g. the table's `tr`) has an attribute like `data-id="itemid"` where itemid is the unique id of the item the row represents

### A simplified version of my update function for sortable:

```
update: function (event, ui)
{
    // Get moved row from ui param
    var $target = $(ui.item);

    // Extract the PK of the item just dragged
    var itemId = parseInt($target.attr('data-id'));

    // Extract the PK of the parent of the items
    var parentId = parseInt($target.parent('table').attr('data-id'));

    // Display order is 1-based in my database so add 1
    var index = $target.index() + 1;

    // Send REST call to server to update new display order
    var url = "/api/reorder/" + itemId.toString() + "?order=" + index.toString() + "&parent="+ parentId.toString();
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: "PUT",
        error: function (xhr, status, error)
        {
            alert(url + " " + error);
        },
        success: function (success: bool, status: string, xhr)
        {
            // success is true if all went well server-side
        }
    });
}
```

Server-side my own REST service is via an MVC API controller, so I will just outline the algorithm below.

### Server-side algorithm:

```
bool Put(itemId, displayOrder, parentId)
{
    var order = 1;
    var listOfOrderedItems = getAllRecordsSortedByDisplayOrderBelongingTo(parentid);  // Some way of fetching just the set of records belonging to the specified parent id
    foreach (var item in listOfOrderedItems)
    {
         // Skip the new insertion point index
         if (order == displayOrder)
         {
              order++;
         }
         // Skip the item we are moving - it gets a new fixed order
         if (item.id != itemId)
         {
             item.DisplayOrder = order++;  // Could use be a SQL update here
         }
         else
         {
             item.DisplayOrder = displayOrder;  // Could use be a SQL update here
         }
    }
}
```

The end result was a `reorderData` plugin I could apply to any table with a line of jQuery like:

```
$(function () {
    $('table.sortable').reorderData();
});
```

[image]
*Note: The drag placeholders (the 3 line icons on the left) are used as I consider it a *bad user-experience* to be able to drag an entire row of data by dragging anywhere in the row. By using `cancel: 'tr>td:not(:first-child)'` in the Sortable options it will only allow dragging by the new drag handle in the first cell of each row.